# how we can reuse subprocess instead of creating again and again in java process builder

Tags: java, process, jvm, processbuilder

I am performing certain action in subprocess which is basically taking input and giving output. each calls input will be different. for now input passing via command line arg. I want to reuse this subprocess instead of creating again and again in each call to make performance optimal. want to reuse same JVM instance because each time when we start() process builder, new process with seperate JVM will created which will load classpath library. Is there any way to achieve this. please share you ideas will help a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Design your process so that offers a different interface than just startup parameters. One way would via network, such as a REST interface. That way your subprocess stays active and is ready for requests. You could also monitor the subprocess's output and write stuff to its System.in.

Comment: One JVM = one process.  If you want to execute multiple actions, sequentially, in that one JVM, then you will have to write a Java program that accepts commands (say, from standard in set to a pipe) and executes each action.  This sounds like adding a lot of complexity.